# iPhone - How to download big amount of files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I need to download a number of files from the server. What is the best way to do it?
All documents are stored in NSMutableArray and for each documents there are two files - the document itself and its change log. So what I do is:

```
- (void)downloadDocuments:(int)docNumber
{
    NSString *urlString;
    NSURL *url;   
    for (int i=0; i<[items count]; i++) {
        [progressBar setProgress:((float)i/[items count]) animated:YES];
        urlString = [[items objectAtIndex:i] docUrl];
        url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [self downloadSingleDocument:url];
        urlString = [[items objectAtIndex:i] changeLogUrl];
        url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [self downloadSingleDocument:url];
    }
    urlString = nil;
    url = nil;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)downloadSingleDocument:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [req addValue:@"Basic XXXXXXX=" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    downloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if (conn == downloadConnection) {
        NSString *filename = [[conn.originalRequest.URL absoluteString] lastPathComponent];
        filename = [filename stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];

        file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath] retain];
        if (file)
        {
            [file seekToEndOfFile];
        }
    }

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (conn == downloadConnection) {
        if (file) { 
            [file seekToEndOfFile];
        }
        [file writeData:data];
    }

}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{

    if (conn==downloadConnection) {
        [file closeFile];
    }
}
```

And my problem is that only the last file is downloaded. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you "overwrite" the member var "downloadConnection" within your loop with a new instance of NSURLConnection (through method call downloadSingleDocument). Doing this leads to the case that the if-statements within your didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData and connectionDidFinish methods will only evaluate to true with the latest created connection. Try using a list of connections to avoid this.

Comment: could you please write an example?

Comment: or maybe you know a better way how to download a list of files?

Comment: Well, instead of "downloadConnection" being a NSURLConnection, you set it to be NSMutableArray. In your "downloadSingleDocument"-method you add the newly created NSURLConnection instance to the list by using [downloadConnection addObject:theConnectionVar]. In your NSURLConnection delegate methods (didReceiveResponse etc.) you loop over all entries in the downloadConnection-Array and for every entry you check if the entry matches the connection-var given as param of the method. If so, this is the matching connection and you can progress as before.

Comment: strange, but it doesn't work...what I do is getFileConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES]; [downloadConnection addObject:getFileConnection]; and then in delegate methods check if ([downloadConnection containsObject:conn])

Comment: also my delegate methods are never triggered, only for the last file in the list

Comment: Try logging a test string to console in didReceiveResponse at first statement tu ensure if it is called proper. In addition you will need to set your file handle as a list of file handles too, my fault to overlook this. You assign in didReceiveResponse the hndle to a single var, but the file downloads may be processed in parallel. That means that the file handle is overwritten by later receiveMessages from other connections and so only one file is proper loaded. If you cannot ensure a sequential download then you cannot reuse any individual var to store connection/file handles.